# How to show that an equation is exponentially stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

I need to show that $\ddot{x}$ + $2\dot{x}$ + $2{x}$ = $0$ is exponentially stable (or the contrary).
The discriminant of the characteristic equation is $-4$, $x_1 = -1 +i$, $x_2 = -1 - i$, so the solution is $$y(x) = e^{-x}(C_{1} cos(x) + C_2sin(x))$$
What are my next steps here? Any help like books or articles with similar examples is appreciated.

Comment: thank you, it should be e^(-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a theorem that states that if an LTI system
$$\tag{1}
\dot {\bar x}=A{\bar x}, \quad {\bar x}\in\mathbb R^n
$$
is asymptotically stable, then it is exponentially stable. Your equation is exactly the system (1) with
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
0&1\\-2&-2
\end{array}\right),\quad {\bar x}=
\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\ \dot x
\end{array}\right).
$$
Indeed,
$$
\ddot{x} + 2\dot{x} + 2x=0
$$
or
$$
\ddot{x}=-2x - 2\dot{x}
$$
can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{d}{dt}x=\dot x= 0\cdot x + 1\cdot \dot x,
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\dot x=\ddot x= -2\cdot x - 2\cdot \dot{x}.
$$
The eigenvalues of $A$ are $-1\pm i$ and since they have negative real parts, the system is asymptotically stable, thus it is exponentially stable.

Comment: Could you explain how you find the matrix A?

Comment: @ouazou I updated the answer

Comment: thank you! How can I find this theorem you mentioned?

Comment: One could also set $v=\dot x+x$, then the equation becomes $\dot v+v+x=0$, or as system $$\pmatrix{\dot x\\\dot v}=\pmatrix{-1&1\\-1&-1}\pmatrix{x\\v},$$ which is as symmetric as it gets. @ouazou

Comment: @ouazou A proof of a slightly broader statement can be found in H. Khalil's book "Nonlinear systems", 3rd edition, in the Example 4.21. If you take $A(t)=A=const$, $P(t)=P=const$, $Q=I$,  you will get the special case of an LTI system. Alternatively, the theorem can be proved using the Jordan normal form for the matrix exponent.

Comment: @AVK I looked again and have a question. What if we have a equation like this $\ddot{x}$ + $6\dot{x}$ + $10$ = $0$ ? Will 10 disappear and the matrix will look like $$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 &  1 \\
 -6 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} $$  ?

Comment: @ouazou
 No, it won't disappear on its own. You will have to make the change of variables $x=\hat x-\frac{10}6t$, $y=\hat y-\frac{10}6$ in the system $\dot x= y$, $\dot y= -6y-10$.

Comment: i finally understand, thank you !